# google places api is missing type of establishment data

Tags: google-places-api

i am trying to figure out where google places is getting its type data from

if one goes to this page https://plus.google.com/104241601063075641206/about?hl=en-US
you can see this establishment is listed as a Billiard Bar but when i look though the details returned from https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

it only lists establishment in the types so i am just wondering where Billiard Bar is coming from?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this information is currently available in the API.  You can star [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5260) to help get the enhancement implemented.

Comment: thats just horible my clients are seeing in in google and wondering why i have been a bad programmer and not including it